# Is it possible to use the same content type field for more than one view?

Tags: views, commerce

I am new to Drupal environment. I have question about [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

I created a view using title and body fields, and added some content.
Later I created one more view using same fields (title and body) and added some extra fields.

In the second view, the first view content also displayed. How to avoid this thing?

Comment: Yes  we use same content type field for more than one view. Can you describe little bit more what you exactly need and what you have tried?

Comment: when i use same fields in more than one views the all the view values are displayed in all the views. for example. i have one view(name: view1 in title and body fields). i have to create one more view using title and body fields in this second view i am getting first view values.

Comment: Are the views of different content types?

Comment: Are the views of different content types?// Same content type body and title are defaults one. i am using all the views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, you can click on Filter and select Content: Type, then select the content type.

[image: check content type]
[image: views filter]

Comment: In this option not available for me.,i am using drupal 7.5

Comment: I am getting page name as one of the view content how to remove it

Comment: This is for Drupal 7.

Comment: Remove the title field if you want to remove the page name.

Comment: Remove the title field if you want to remove the page name // thanks this one working